# debugger trap with angr

Tags: anti-debugging, angr

Let's suppose this (very ugly) c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

char sav_argv[100];

void on_sigtrap(int signo)
{
    if (strcmp(sav_argv, "hello") == 0)
    {
        printf("OK!\n");
    } else {
        printf("NOK\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    memset(sav_argv,100,0);
    memcpy(sav_argv,argv[1],100);
    signal(SIGTRAP,on_sigtrap);
    __asm__("int3");
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled this c program with gcc (linux 64 bits elf).

What i want to do is to solve it with an angr python script.
It does work if i remove the debuger trap but it does not work with debuger trap.

Is there a way to make angr work on this c program ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a [hook](https://docs.angr.io/docs/simprocedures.html) on the `int3`. [Docs](http://angr.io/api-doc/angr.html#angr.project.Project.hook).

Comment: Good idea but what should i put in hook function? How can i call handler ?

Comment: Look in the Control Flow section. You can put a `jump(addr)` to transfer control to the handler.

Comment: is it a jump or a call in this case ?

Comment: Will likely be a call.

Comment: I do not see example with hook, int3 and call

Comment: When the int3 instruction is triggered you should jump (change the instruction pointer) to the on_sigtrap function.

Comment: I have understood but i did not managed to make it work (syntax)